# Porting from centos 2.6 to 3.10

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system

Can any one tell as how is /etc/mtab is getting updated in centos 3.10
mount operation differs compared with centos 2.6 and 3.10 version.

Comment: `/etc/mtab` reflect mount options, used for actual mounting. Usually them come from `/etc/fstab`. Sometimes `/etc/mtab` is just a link to `/proc/mount`, so its format is not always the same. What exact difference you found?

Comment: proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0

Comment: what does the last 2 numbers 0 and 0 mean ? this entry exists in /etc/mtab

Comment: Last two numbers are `dump` and `check` flags correspondingly. You can read `man fstab` for more detailed info.

Comment: Trying to perform mount advfs on centos 7 kernel. The operation mount happens, but the entry of mount is erroneous. the mount performs the read from /etc/mtab and the below line is displayed.                                                                   

/dev/fs_name/domain_name/fs_name    /mnt   fs_name  rw,relatime,°8Â^A 0 0
can anyone explain what is expected after relatime in the entry.